# Android LogCat in eclipse: How to filter the LogCat message?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-logcat

I just want the messages about a specific application, what should I type in this:

[image: add a new logcat filter]

I cannot find Appname in AndroidManifest.xml...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just filter logcat error ( or whatever you want ) by providing `Filter Name` with the `source tag` and `by Application Name` by your `package name`.

ex

[image]